# CloudKit: Cannot create a new field type in production schema

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have deployed CloudKit development environment to production. Previously I have tested my app in Development environment, it worked without any error. Now running app in Production environment and when client wants to insert a record in CloudKit I get this error:

```
Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x17fddd60; 0188D8FE-F9EB-49A0-9CC2-A2AE513E9E25:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: Cannot create a new field type in production schema
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: When you migrate to production all recordTypes should have been created the same as they are on development. It looks like you are writing a record with a field that did not exist before and therefore cannot be written to the production environment. Make sure you add this field to development and then migrate it to production again.

Answer (score 9):

You can only create new record types or fields in the Development environment of CloudKit, not Production.  If these were fields that you already have in Development, make sure that you have deployed your schema to Production (In the iCloud Dashboard, click Deployment at the bottom of the menu on the left hand side, then click Deploy to Production)